# Does flash play .avi or .mpg4 ? If yes, how?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, avi, mpeg

How to load and play .avi or .mpg4 in Flash? Is that possible ?

-> This class can play .flv and also .mp4 .. but for .avi it shows error "Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound"

```
package src {     
    import flash.display.Sprite;     
    import flash.media.Video;     
    import flash.net.NetConnection;     
    import flash.net.NetStream;      
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        public class vplayer extends Sprite{                 
            public var vid:Video = new Video(1920,1080);
            private var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            public var ns:NetStream;
            public var listener:Object = new Object();
            private var _duration:Number = 0; 

            public function vplayer():void{             
                addChild(vid);
                nc.connect(null);
                ns = new NetStream(nc);
                vid.attachNetStream(ns);
                listener.onMetaData = metaDataHandler;
                ns.client = listener;           
                //customClient.onCuePoint = cuePointHandler;
            }
            public function playVideo00(vv:String):void{

                ns.play(vv);
            }
            public function stopVideo00():void{
                ns.close();
            }
            /*public function cuePointHandler(infoObject:Object):void {
                trace("cuePoint");
            }*/
            public function metaDataHandler(infoObject:Object):void {
                _duration = infoObject["duration"];
                trace (" Time:  " + infoObject["duration"]);
            }
            public function get duration00():Number {     
                return _duration; 
            }
        } 
}
```

.. any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is an MP4 on a streaming server, you simply need to prefix your video file name with "mp4:" when making the RTMP call. You need to be sure to only add it to the actual video file, not the full URL.

Example:

If your full video is at `rtmp://domain.com/dir/myVideo.mp4` then you would prefix `myVideo.mp4` when you call the `play()` function.

`ns.play("mp4:myVideo");`

Depending on your streaming server's settings you may or may not need the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

[this example](http://wonderfl.net/c/3dVV) can play `.mp4` files

Answer (score 1):

File extension actually doesn't mean that much.  AVI, QuickTime, etc are container formats and the audio and video stream formats (ie, codecs) inside them can vary.  With some, the container format can vary, too.

The [Flash Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) article on Wikipedia summarizes things fairly well as far as what is playable in what version of Flash Player.

As far as playing video, you can either make your own player using [FLVPlayback](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/flvplayback_component.html) or use a common player like [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/).

Comment: This class can play .flv and also .mp4 .. but for .avi it shows error "Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound"

Comment: Did you read the articles I mentioned?  I highly doubt that you AVI actually contains audio/video that Flash Player can decode.  In other words, it isn't a function of the AS3 class that you use.  All video players essentially call the same functions.  The issue is what audio/video formats Flash Player itself can decode.

Comment: That`s true, and also, playing an AVI file from a web page is not good thing to do, AVI`s file size mostly is big. So maybe Adobe prefers to support flv and mp4 rather than avi. @ MPD